# how to add an url in xamarin.forms app

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

hi I want to build a simple xamarin.forms app so I have the xaml code here so in this code I want to add website url so can anyone please help what options do i need to add in xaml code to add the website url ? I want to add link below the label groceries when I tried to add url using label and text options the url remained just like label but I want it in such a way that if I click on the url it should take me to the site in browser .

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MyApp.AboutPage">
   <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
 VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Label Text="My List" />
        <Label Text="groceries"/>
        <Button BackgroundColor="black" TextColor="White" WidthRequest="40" 
  HeightRequest="40" Text="OK" Clicked="OnRedirectMain" 
   BorderColor="Transparent" BorderWidth="1"/>

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
 </ContentPage>
```

Comment: what does "want to add website url" mean?  Do you just want to display it in your app?  Or do you want the user to be able to click on it?  Should it open inside of the app, or open an external browser?

Comment: I want the user to be able to click on it and it should open in an external browser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<Button Text="Google" Clicked="GoGoogle" />

protected void GoGoogle(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Device.OpenUri(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
}
```

if you don't want to use a Button, you can use a Label with a gesture

```
<Label Text="Google">
  <Label.GestureRecognizers>
      <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="GoGoogle" />
  </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>

protected void GoGoogle(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      Device.OpenUri(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
    }
```

Comment: Instead of button I want to display the url on screen and on click of url it should open in external browser ,for example I want to display on the screen as  "www.google.com"  and when user clicks on this link it should open in external browser ,can you please let me know instead of button what should i give for url in xaml ? thanks

Comment: if you have specific requirements, you should include them in your original post so people don't waste their time writing answers that aren't going to be helpful.

Comment: hi can you help me with this please ?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49863507/task-failed-because-aximp-exe-was-not-found-error-is-visual-studio-for-mac-in-x?noredirect=1#comment86743004_49863507

Answer (score 1):

For those who are trying to achieve the same in 2023:

The following command is obsolete

`Device.OpenUri(new Uri(""));`

Use this command instead:

```
Launcher.OpenAsync(new Uri("https://typeyoururlhere.com"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Label>

    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span Text="Go to SO" ForegroundColor="Blue"/>
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>

    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
          <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="GoToSO" />
    </Label.GestureRecognizers>

</Label>

protected void GoToSO(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Device.OpenUri(new Uri("http://www.stackoverflow.com"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ICommands with MVVM you can do the following:

Use a ViewModel which has an ICommand property:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // details redacted ...

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        //...
        OpenGoogleCommand = new Command(() => Device.OpenUri(new Uri("http://www.google.com")));
    }
    public ICommand OpenGoogleCommand { get; }
}
```

You then bind the command in the label:

```
<Label>
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <FormattedString.Spans>
                <Span Text="Link to Google" FontSize="Large"
                      TextColor="Blue"
                      FontAttributes="Bold"/>
            </FormattedString.Spans>
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OpenGoogleCommand}" />
    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```